# Need help identifying this popup/program

Tags: windows-11

I hope this isn't off-topic, sorry if it is.

Today I started seeing this popup. I've never seen it before. I went through add/remove programs and don't see anything new or unexpected.  It's popped up probably 20 times today. If I try to close it, it just comes back. If I try to click "show details" nothing happens.

[image: Desktop Window]

[image: Taskbar Icons]

**UPDATE 1**

I determined the file running is `msrdc.exe`. There are two copies of it on my PC:
`\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`
`\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_8wekyb3d8bbwe`

Both are zero bytes. I still need to know why it keeps popping up and, apparently, trying to make a connection. I ran malwarebytes and it found nothing.

**UPDATE 2**

I have it running persistently while I have WSL (Bash for Ubuntu) open. It just sits there trying to "connect". Running TCPView shows no active connection attempts from MSRDC.EXE. However, Process Monitor shows tons of this for the following command:

```
msrdc.exe /v:733DA5B1-DF5B-4E02-80AD-51F7970D87B5 /hvsocketserviceid:7A4013BC-FACB-11E6-BD58-64006A7986D3 /silent /wslg /plugin:WSLDVC_PACKAGE /wslgsharedmemorypath:WSL\733DA5B1-DF5B-4E02-80AD-51F7970D87B5\wslg "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_1.1.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wslg.rdp"
```

And it is definitely running from `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_1.1.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msrdc.exe`

I opened up `wslg.rdp` and it looks like this:

```
audiocapturemode:i:2
authentication level:i:0
disableconnectionsharing:i:1
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
hvsocketenabled:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
remoteapplicationprogram:s:dummy-entry
```

**UPDATE 3**

I closed WSL and closed the popup. It came back with an odd `p`. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

[image]
[image]

It's doing a LOT of registry and file operations repeatedly, but I'm still not seeing any network activity.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it might be Windows Remote Desktop. I get the connection screen you see when I connect to another operating system.

Comment: My RDP screen looks a bit different: https://imgur.com/QAUnPmc

Comment: Although I do now have this weird resizable blank window that was never there before: https://imgur.com/y6TZi5x

Comment: Look in Control Panel, Programs and Features for what that might be.

Comment: @THEJOATMON - Before we blame `Windows Remote Desktop` are you even using `Windows Remote Desktop` for anything? Are you able to use ProcessExplorer in order to identify the executable?

Comment: I have not used RDP today at all, except to capture screenshots for @John. So no, while the issue in question was happening, RDP was not in use.

Comment: @THEJOATMON - So it can't be the `Windows Remote Desktop` unless you have malware attempting to make a remote desktop connection with a malicious user's own desktop (which makes no sense)

Comment: In your update, you mention `MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux`. Are you using WSL for anything, or using programs that require it?

Comment: I had not launched WSL at all today. However, I just did to test and immediately the popup appeared and is STAYING as long as I keep bash open. I'm currently running `netstat -b` to see what it is attempting to connect to.

Comment: related? ("msrdc continously restarting #901" ) https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/901

Comment: What is under the show details drop menu?

Comment: The "show details" link/button does nothing.

Comment: After rebooting I cannot get this to come back, even opening WSL manually.  The world may never know what was happening... :)

Comment: I never said it was. Did I?

Comment: "I still need to know why it keeps popping up and, apparently, trying to make a connection." - It's trying to make a remote connection to your WSL2 desktop.  It's not clearly NOT malicious. To confirm you are trying to make a remote connection to your WSL2 Desktop you would have to provide your `.wslgconfig`. Were you using Citrix Desktop by chance?

Answer (score 0):

The popup might be a window of a Linux application of your WSL installation. [WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg), a component of WSL, is using Remote Desktop to display Linux GUI applications on your Windows Desktop.

> WSLg is short for Windows Subsystem for Linux GUI and the purpose of
> the project is to enable support for running Linux GUI applications
> (X11 and Wayland) on Windows in a fully integrated desktop experience.